# Using Jquery in modular web site

Tags: jquery

I am building a website following the atomic design/development method, ie with a modular system.

For example, I create a slider module and a slider banner module and only call them into a page when needed which is all well and good eg.

```
<?php include("../organisms/main-slider.php");?> 
<?php include("../organisms/slider-banner.php");?>
```

However each module may have their own corresponding  jquery code, in some cases we use JQuery and this code obviously has to be below the library at the end of the page. What is the best solution for this so that we only load the jquery when it is needed but also so it is loaded after the library. I understand it's more of a structural question than a programming question, but not sure where else to ask. A corresponding js file for each module too?

Comment: Include jQuery at the top on every page. Once a user has visited your home page jquery.js will be in their browser's cache and won't need to download again for your other pages.

Comment: but is this best practice, on first load having to load the jquery library first?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, best solution for loading dependent JavaScript files is AMD. For that purpose you can use Requirejs which is a framework that manages all your dependencies. You can learn to use it in [Requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) site.

I hope this is helpful.